# Regex to check for the pattern YYYY-MM-dd is coming in a string variable

Tags: java, regex, date

I have a string variable named dateStr  now this variable dateStr can have these possible values

```
21/02/2014
05/25/2014
05/12/16
2016/12/26  (YYYY/MM-dd)   ****//check this pattern format  *******
2014-JAN-04 (YYYY-MMM-dd)   ****//check this pattern format ********
```

Now please advise any regex expression by which i can check for the formats YYYY/MM/dd and YYYY-MM-dd that is basically in which year is coming first part

so please advise any regex expression to cross heck that first four digits are YYYY so please advise how to check this can we buid any regex check in which lets say if first three digits are not integer or the third digit is - or / then the string is not in YYYY-MM-dd format please advise the correct regex for that

Comment: It would be a lot easier to try to parse the date and catch any exceptions...

Comment: " a lot slower" being 0.02ms instead of 0.015ms?  And a regex that properly handled month names and leap years and made sure `/` or `-` was used consistently would burn a lot more CPU cycles.

Comment: @Grogi I'd say the opposite: a regex that properly validates the date is probably going to be slower (your current answer would possibly be faster but performs no validation and looks too simplistic for what the OP requires)! And if the OP needs to use the date later on it will need to be parsed anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is not absolutely clear about the requirements, but this should show the direction:

```
\d{4}([-/])(\d{2}|\w{3})\1\d{2}
```

If you searching for English month names, then you could replace `\w{3}` with `JAN|FEB|MAR` and so on. Also you could improve the expression with some value constraints for the month and day values:

```
\d{4}([-/])(0[1-9]|1[012]|JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\1(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])
```

This would exclude values like `9999/FOO-99` or `2016-02/01`, but matches `2016/02/01` and `2016-02-01`.

Keep in mind that the usage of a regular expression can not check for invalid dates like `2016-02-31`.

Comment: `9999/FOO-99` would be a valid date according to that.

Comment: @spash well the question was lets say if the date is coming as dd-MM-YYYY or MM-dd-YYYY then first three digit consist contains - or / and lets say if the format is coming as YYYY-MM-dd or YYYY/MM/dd then in first three digit the value is Y so basically i have to check that year is coming as YYYY-MM-dd or YYYY/MM/dd then for that case if i have to do something

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I don't need date validation my issue was to catch that date was coming in which format specially I have to track the dates coming in string variable in yyyy-MM-dd  or yyyy/mm/dd format so now please advise your solution works for both the cases now

Answer (score 0):

`(?:\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})|(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`

Comment: can you please explain a little detail about regarding the checking  in the above regex please doest it checking that the string contains first as yyyy then proceed ot it contains / or - at 3 position then not to proceed

Comment: can i also interpret it as if ((?:\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})|(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})) then date string is in yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy/mm/dd format